# What gas law is involved when your ears "pop" when you are on a plane high in the air?

Tags: gas-laws, pressure, kinetic-theory-of-gases, ideal-gas

When you are up in the air, the air pressure decreases and the altitude increases. What gas law is involved in the situation wherein your ears "pop" because of the difference in pressure.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187905/why-do-our-ears-pop

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic. Physics at best, definitely no chemitry.

Comment: @Karl to be fair, such things are discussed in any introductory chemistry text.

Comment: Karl, I think you will agree that there is no distinct boundary between chemistry and physics.

Answer (score 2):

The temperature and the volume of the inner ear are constant. When your ears pop during descent, air from the cabin goes into the ear, increasing the pressure. The law is the following:

$$n / P = const$$

You can derive this from the ideal gas law. It has no special name.